# RN 0.59 build fails on XCode 13.3 M1 Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I couldn't get out on my issue.

I am using `react-native: 0.59`

- XCode 13.3
- Monterey M1

When I am building on Xcode I got this error

[image]

What I already did

- pod deintegrate
- pod install
- reinstalling packages
- unlinking and linking
- removing DerivedData and Pods
- Running XCode in Rosetta
- Manually liking the libraries
- Changing Deployment settings [image]
- Editing RCTBridgeModule
  [image]

Still no luck.

Please get me out of here. Thank you.